# I am working with django rest framework, I am using pygments for highlighting the code, but I got syntax error as in pygmentify.py

Tags: django-rest-framework

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /snippets/
Exception Value: invalid syntax (pygmentify.py, line 13)

Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/snippets/

Django Version: 1.11.2
Python Version: 3.6.1

```
Installed Applications:   
['snippets.apps.SnippetsConfig',   
'django.contrib.admin',   
'django.contrib.auth',   
'django.contrib.contenttypes',   
'django.contrib.sessions',   
'django.contrib.messages',   
'django.contrib.staticfiles',   
'rest_framework',   
'django_pygments']
```

**'snippets.models':**

```
from django.db import models    ``                    
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers, get_lexer_by_name                       
from pygments.formatters.html import HtmlFormatter 
from pygments import highlight  
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]    
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])    
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())    


class Snippet(models.Model):    
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)    
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')    
   code = models.TextField()      
   linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)    
   language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', 
   max_length=100)    
   style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', 
   max_length=100)    
   owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='snippets', 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
   highlighted = models.TextField()    

   class Meta:    
      ordering = ('created',)    

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
       lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)    
       linenos = self.linenos and 'table' or False    
       options = self.title and {'title': self.title} or {}    
       formatter = HtmlFormatter(style=self.style, linenos=linenos,
                              full=True, **options)    
       self.highlighted = highlight(self.code, lexer, formatter)    
       super(Snippet, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: yes, I read the error message, but I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package not support python 3. 
The release version 0.1 not support yet, but the dev version 0.3 did it, but they never release that version

Answer (score 0):

You can directly install this github repo and it'll work. https://github.com/odeoncg/django-pygments
`pip install git+https://github.com/odeoncg/django-pygments.git`